# How to get google optimize experiment name?

Tags: ab-testing, google-optimize

I am trying to get my google optimize experiments names from my app code,
but I didn't find out how to do this.

Is it possible?

I only managed to get the experiments IDs by using window.gaData

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, you can't get experiment **names** outside of Optimize 360.  You can only get experiment **IDs** and **variant numbers**.

However, you could create your own object of test information, using your `dataLayer` to store your website/test data.

I'll post part of my answer, from this post:
[Is it possible to read ExperimentId and VariationId in Javascript with Google Optimize?][1]

A bit more of a clunky way to do it, but in Optimize 360:

1. You could add additional JavaScript/test information into each variant, (when you go edit your AB Test/variants).
2. And send your experiment name and any other information, to your dataLayer, via `dataLayer.push();

An example:

```
// IF YOU WANT TO PASS THE DATE THE TEST WAS LAUNCHED
function returnDate() {
  var today = new Date();
  var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
  var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
  
  today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
  return today;
}

var dateToday = returnDate();

// YOUR AB TEST INFORMATION
var ABTest = {

      id: 'YOUREXPERIMENTID',
      name: 'Title of your test',
      description:  'Test description',
      date: dateToday, //The launch date of AB Test.
      variant: 1,
      totalVariants: 5
  };

// AND THEN PUSH ALL THAT INFORMATION INTO THE DATALAYER 
dataLayer.Tests.push(ABTest);
```

Then to access all that information, all you need to do is access the `window.dataLayer` object.

Now I've used google tag manager, to add the "Test" key, in dataLayer.Tests. But of course you don't need that, but I just like to organise my object :)